# I hit an error when I try to add a new comment to my database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I run into an error that says:

> *The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Comments_dbo.Posts_PostID". The conflict occurred in database "MVCProjectApp.Models.DBPostsContext", table "dbo.Posts", column 'PostID'.
>
>   The statement has been terminated.*

I am lost and not sure what to do

Here is the create comment

```
@model MVCProjectApp.Models.Comment

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Comment";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Comments</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Message)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Timestamp)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Timestamp)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Timestamp)
        </div>


        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "~/FullPost/Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

This is the Actionlink where I am passing the postid to the comment create

```
//
        // GET: /Comment/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.PostID = new SelectList(db.Posts, "PostID", "Title");
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Comment/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Comment comment)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Comments.Add(comment);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.PostID = new SelectList(db.Posts, "PostID", "Title", comment.PostID);
            return View(comment);
        }
```

here is the comment model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCProjectApp.Models
{
    public class Post
    {
        public int PostID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }
    public class Comment
    {
        public int CommentID { get; set; }
        public int PostID { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It says that the postid you are providing as foreign key does not exist in its primary table.

Answer (score 1):

> I am lost and not sure what to do

You should take a look at the error you're getting. It says you're trying to insert a Comment. The foreign key constraint check that's ran by the DBMS before an insert tries to make sure the Comment has a PostID that it knows. You don't set it, so it'll default to 0, which does not exist in the Posts table, hence the error.

You should set the Comment's PostID before calling `SaveChanges()`, which can be done by adding a `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PostID)` field in the view. You then set the PostID of the model in the controller.

Comment: How do I pass the postid variable, it is in the url when I go to the comment page

Comment: @Scott that depends on your URL. You can for example use `Request.QueryString["ProjectID"]`.

Comment: How do I set the postid in the controller

Answer (score 0):

you need to associate the comment to the post. the simplest solution is to add a hidden field for the post id to the view.

Comment: I have tried @html.hiddenfor(model => model.PostID) but then the database did not create anything

Comment: the hidden field is within the form, correct? `PostID` should be set in the comment model. if that doesn't work, you can load the `Post` object from the database and add the `Comment` to the `post.Comments` collection.